# Redirect Facebook Scraper to /?_escaped_fragment_= with HTML5 history URLs (no hashbang) for AJAX content

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

If you use hashbang URLs, a la `/#!/path/to/content`, the Facebook scraper (as well as the Googlebot) will automatically forward to `/?_escaped_fragment_=/path/to/content`, where you can render content server-side for the scraper to use.

For Google, if you include a fragment meta tag (`<meta name="fragment" content="!">`), you can use HTML5 history style URLs (e.g., simply `/path/to/content`) and it will still know to redirect to the escaped fragment URL.

Facebook doesn't seem to support this. It *will* redirect to whatever you set the `og:url` meta tag to, but I'm not sure that this is proper usage of the og:url tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after talking to you today on twitter and doing my own research the only solution I found that suits me is as follows:

I am using node+express. I check query string first for google crawler, but if user agent is facebook I use this instead for my fragment variable. Then I parse the url and match one of the snapshots that I have created with grunt-htmlSnapshot plugin.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'];

      var fragment = req.query._escaped_fragment_;

      if (userAgent.indexOf('facebookexternalhit') >= 0) {
        fragment = req.url;
      }

      // If there is no fragment in the query params
      // then we're not serving a crawler
      if (!fragment) return next();

      // If the fragment is empty, serve the
      // index page
      if (fragment === "" || fragment === "/")
        fragment = "/.html";

      // If fragment does not start with '/'
      // prepend it to our fragment
      if (fragment.charAt(0) !== "/")
        fragment = '/' + fragment;

      // If fragment does not end with '.html'
      // append it to the fragment
      if (fragment.indexOf('.html') == -1)
        fragment += ".html";

      fragment = fragment.replace(/\//g, '_');
      // Serve the static html snapshot
      try {
        var file = "./snapshots/snapshot_" + fragment;
        res.sendfile(file);
      } catch (err) {
        res.send(404);
      }
    });
```

All my snapshots are stored in ./snapshots and example of snapshot for "/contact/" page is: ./snapshots/snapshot__contact.html

This is all tested and works great!

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but I believe you can sniff out the Facebook bot's user agent and forward it to an `/?_escaped_fragment_` URL based on that.